# Firebase notification based on user login session

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have added firebase push notifications in my app, I am sending notification messages using data payload only as I need notification data whether app is in background or foreground. I have a login system in my app. In **onMessageReceived** method of `FirebaseMessagingService` I am checking whether the user is currently logged in or not and based on that notification is delivered. It works fine as long as the user is logged in, after user logout and login again any pending notifications are not sent. I do not know how to handle this scenario. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: by `pending notifications`, u mean the notifications between logout and next login?

Comment: yes, if the user is currently not logged in and notification is fired from the backend, then it should receive notification as soon as it login again

Comment: Then you will have to persist those notifications in database when no session is found and after login, dispatch a job (or async) to check the database and fire those notifications. Be sure to clear the database after firing

Comment: Okay ,thanks. That should work . Let me check with backend team

Comment: When i said `database` i meant the mobile database like sqlite, not the backend server.

Comment: Oh okay, Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks! Cerlin it is working perfectly

Comment: hello, late comment but what did you do to solve this problem

Comment: I saved the notifications using sqlite and then on login of user checking whether there are any pending notifications of that user in db and after showing deleting data from database

Answer (score 2):

You should trigger(notify server) an event on logout so that when User is logged out,
Server Should not fire any content in that case.
Maintain an queue(content) on server-end so that whenever user log-in again dispatch the data to users.
Note:- Queue should be valid for some time limit otherwise for long time Queue can become too large and will hamper server.

Comment: I followed Cerlin Boss logic and it worked perfectly

Comment: Your app should remain light, too many storage in app could lead app's heaviness and have to compute more on app-end like as Cerlin Boss said " when no session is found and after login, dispatch a job (or async) to check the database and fire those notifications. Be sure to clear the database after firing". \In general the part of notification should be maintain at server end

Comment: yes we will clear the notifications after they are fired